# Can this be made to work on a remote computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've been killing myself trying to get this to work on a remote computer, is it even possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's the code:

```
    Function Lock-WorkStation { 
        #Requires -Version 2.0 
        $signature = @" 
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
            public static extern bool LockWorkStation(); 
        "@ 

        $LockWorkStation = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name "Win32LockWorkStation" -namespace Win32Functions -passthru 
        $LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test here, but for me it can NOT work because, as you can read in [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.),  the `LockWorkStation` function is callable only by processes running on the interactive desktop. In addition, the user must be logged on.

So when you connect to a remote computer using PSSession as far as I understand you are not in the interactive session.

Comment: Yeah, PSremoting isolates the remote session.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. But you need a workaround to connect to the interactive session.

Download the [PowerShellPack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) and install it. You only need one module called "TaskScheduler".

I've tested the following code:

```
Function Lock-Workstation
{
param(
$Computername,
$Credential
)
    if(!(get-module taskscheduler)){Import-Module TaskScheduler}
    New-task -ComputerName $Computername -credential:$Credential | 
    Add-TaskTrigger -In (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30) |
    Add-TaskAction -Script `
    { 
    $signature = @" 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
    public static extern bool LockWorkStation(); 
"@ 
    $LockWorkStation = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature `
                                -name "Win32LockWorkStation" `
                                -namespace Win32Functions `
                                -passthru 
    $LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null
    } | Register-ScheduledTask TestTask -ComputerName $Computername `
                                        -credential:$Credential
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Lock-Workstation "NameOfTheComputer" (Get-Credential)
```

or like this:

```
Lock-Workstation "NameOfTheComputer"
```

If you receive an error in Connect-ToTaskScheduler when specifying a credential, it's because there is a typo in the module (edit Connect-ToTaskScheduler.ps1 and replace **"$NetworkCredentail.Domain,"** with **"$NetworkCredential.Domain,"**

Comment: Two questions : 1) do you test it on a remote computer running Vista or upper system ? 2) Do you really test it with a different user logged on the remote machine ? That means the admin can use the taskscheduler to inject code in interactive desktop.

Comment: 1) I ran it from a Windows 7 workstation to a Windows 2008 R2 server.
2) Both computers have the same user logged on.

Comment: To run it remotely with a different credential, you can specify -credential to both new-task and register-scheduledtask.

Comment: So you need to have the credential of the user logged on the remote computer. In this way I understand, thanks WinFred. I don't think this is an operational solution but +1 for the idea.

Comment: What I was looking to do was to be able to add this function to a Module, and then call it from the console like so:
`Lock-Workstation comp1`
And then have that lock the computer named comp1. I have a function I can use to force a logoff, but ideally I'd like to just be able to lock the workstation.

Comment: I've turned it into a function. Now you can either dot source it or load it into your profile.

Comment: To JPBlanc, actually this script works also without these permissions, as long as the account that starts has administrative rights (I just this out when I accidentally started it with a different account than the logged on account and it worked fine).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with this, but it can help in Windows Vista/7 2008/R2, you can use the command `tsdiscon.exe` to lock a Remote Desktop session or your workstation.

Here is a sample where, logged as adminstrator domain on my computer, I first list, then lock the console session on my server.

```
PS> query session /server:WM2008R2ENT
 SESSION           UTILISATEUR              ID  ÉTAT    TYPE        PÉRIPHÉRIQUE
 services                                    0  Déco
 console           jpb                       2  Actif

PS> tsdiscon 2 /server:WM2008R2ENT
```